# При изменение разрешения экрана элементы съезжают со своих мест - HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Доброго времени суток)столкнулся вот с такой проблемой,при моем разрешении все хорошо отображается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я начинаю менять разрешение,к примеру на 960х840 элементы съезжают
[image: 960х840]

как это можно исправить?Спасибо!

Comment: А код где? Предлагаешь нам самим всё с нуля сделать по скриншоту?

Comment: я просто думал подскажите в каком напрвление двигаться

Comment: Для начала добавьте в вопрос код

Comment: Двигайтесь в направлении адаптивной верстки.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1 - использовать CSS фреймворк типо Bootstrap, он сделает адаптив за вас

Вариант 2 - использовать media запросы и задавать размеры элементов в процентах, а не пикселях

В любом случае надо двигаться в сторону адаптивной верстки

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужна адаптивная верстка:

- Bootstrap( http://getbootstrap.com/ )
- Медиа запросы( https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp )
- Zurb Foundation( https://foundation.zurb.com/ )